# Format date pulled from API - React

Tags: reactjs, datetime

I am currently using componentDidMount to display API data onto my webpage. Most of data are dates i.e. 'due date' '_field' and they display as MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm, however I want to reformat the dates to MM/dd/yyyy on my webpage. not sure where to start, I am familiar with var date = new Date() but not sure if that is to be used in this case

```
        render() {
        var {items} = this.state
        return (
        ....
        <tbody>

        {items.map(item => ( 

            <tr key={item.summary_type}>

            <td> {item.summary_type} </td>
            <td> {item.supplier_status} </td>
            <td> {item.due_date} </td>
            <td> {item.iso_field} </td>
            <td> {item.as_field} </td>
            <td> {item.nadcap_field} </td>
            <td> {item.cert_field} </td>
            <td> {item.extension_field} </td>

            </tr>
            ))}
            </tbody>
            ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to return the first part of the date that you need:

```
   getDate = (date) => {
     return date.split(' ')[0]
    }

    render() {
    var {items} = this.state
    return (
    ....
    <tbody>

    {items.map(item => ( 

        <tr key={item.summary_type}>

        <td> {item.summary_type} </td>
        <td> {item.supplier_status} </td>
        <td> {this.getDate(item.due_date)} </td>
        <td> {item.iso_field} </td>
        <td> {item.as_field} </td>
        <td> {item.nadcap_field} </td>
        <td> {item.cert_field} </td>
        <td> {item.extension_field} </td>

        </tr>
        ))}
        </tbody>
        ....
```

Comment: Thanks! i used "return date.split('  ', 1)"  to perform the same function and if I am understanding it right I am splitting it once and outputting only the mm/dd/yyyy? in your example does the "[0]" mean split past index 0?

Comment: Yes that's it `date.split(' ', 1)` it's also another good solution, the split method in this case it create an array of two elements, [MM/dd/yyyy, HH:mm] with the [0] we are saying that we want only the element in first position

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of the exact input or output, but you can make use of [Date.toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to get the desired date string that you need.

```js
const now = new Date();
const dateString = now.toLocaleDateString({
  weekday: "short",
  year: "numeric",
  month: "2-digit",
  day: "numeric"
})

console.log(dateString);
```